# Lebesgue measure and continuos functions

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have posed a very interesting problem but I have not managed to give an example of a sequence of continuous functions ($f_n$) defined in the unit square $[0,1]$, $0\leq f_n \leq 1$ that does not converge to any point but $\int f_n \to 0$.

can anyone help me!!

Comment: Did you mean the unit interval? Either way there is a standard "moving block" construction that you should be able to look up using that term.

Answer (score 0):

Just check here https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-around-dominated-convergence-theorem/

The paragraph named *The case of a nowhere converging function* is what you are looking for.